# jQuery: run animation on text with timing

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to run the animation on two text lines which show the first text line for 5s and then other text line for 5s with the fadein and fadeout. which show the first line and the other and same for second. But at the first time this jQuery code show the the both line at the same time.

```js
setInterval(function() {  
  $('#move_text div:first')
    .fadeOut(800)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(800)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#move_text');
}, 5000);
$('#move_text').addClass('move_text');
```

```css
.move_text{
  position:relative;
  animation:move_Ist 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move_Ist 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation:move_Ist 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes move_Ist {
  0% {
    left:-80%;  
  }
  
  25% {
    left:0%; 
  }
  
  75% {
    left:-3%; 
  }
  
  100% {
    left:105%; 
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move_Ist {
  0% {
    left:-80%; 
  }
  
  25% {
    left:0%; 
  }
  
  75% {
    left:-3%; 
  }
  
  100% {
    left:105%;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes move_Ist {
  0% {
    left:-80%;
  }
  
  25% {
    left:0%;
  }
  
  75% {
    left:-3%; 
  }
  
  100% {
    left:105%; 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="move_text">
  <div id="text1">
    <p1>programming is my Passion</p1>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="text2">
    <p2>i Love Technology</p2>
  </div> 
</div>
```

This code show both text line at the same time. I want tos how one and then the other.

Comment: It looks like `#text2` isn't starting out hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
#text2 {
  display: none;
}
```

to your CSS.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gh3WX/) here - seems to work OK.